# How to set request cookie header in Feign Client

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, openfeign

I have a basic FeingClient and I need to set a cookie in the request headers so that I have a valid response. I don't really know how to do this, I have tried with @Headers and @Header as well but no success. I need for the /dogs request to have the CUSTOM_TOKEN set like I see in Postman (Cookie: CUSTOM_COOKIE={VALUE})

```
@FeignClient(value = "petShopApi", url="http://localhost:8080/pets")
public interface PetShopFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/dogs")
    Response getResponse(@CookieValue("CUSTOM_TOKEN") String token);

}
```